# PHP to nested object JSON output

Tags: php, json

Currently I have the below JSON as my out put from my php function (also below). However, I need the initial brackets for name list to change from [] to {}. I see this kind of output with actual APIs but I cannot figure out how to make this happen. Any suggestions?
JSON Output file:

```
    {
    "nameList": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "Name": "Test",
                "Amount": 0,
                "Location": "Test"
            }
    ]
}
```

PHP Code:

```
$json = json_encode(array("nameList" => array($MySQL->ReturnDataArray("*","names","WHERE Location = '". $Location ."'")), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
        file_put_contents('/assets/server/output.json', $json);
```

Comment: Why do you need this change?

Comment: A plugin that I am trying to use only grabs objects with the {} brackets.

Comment: Odd. It would seem a plugin could use valid JSON

Comment: what do you want to do if nameList has multiple objects in there

Comment: Can you show what you want the output to be like? You say you've seen it from other APIs, but that doesn't seem likely since you want invalid JSON.

Answer (score 1):

You are explicitly wrapping your data in array:

```
$data = $MySQL->ReturnDataArray("*","names","WHERE Location = '". $Location ."'");
$json = json_encode(array("nameList" => array($data), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT); // inside []
$json = json_encode(array("nameList" => $data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT); // without []
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` to achieve this

```
json_encode($foo, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT)
```

or in your case

```
json_encode($foo, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)
```

But listen to the comments. It is not really a good idea. An array should be an array.

But maybe you want something else.... Lets split your commands:

```
$step1 = $MySQL->ReturnDataArray("*","names","WHERE Location = '". $Location ."'");

$step2 = array($step1);

$step3 = array("nameList" => $step2);

$step4 = json_encode($step3, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Maybe you want to remove step2!!! So try it like this:

```
$step1 = $MySQL->ReturnDataArray("*","names","WHERE Location = '". $Location ."'");

//$step2 = array($step1);

$step3 = array("nameList" => $step1);

$step4 = json_encode($step3, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: Using force object changes the array completely to: {"nameList":{"0":{"id":1,"Name":"Test","Amount":0,"Location":"Test"}}}, how would you get the secondary "0" out of there. Also, if an array should be an array then why do companies like rottentomato output it with {} instead of []

Comment: Yes, an Object has always an index. You want an Object? You need an index!

Comment: @DreadedSlug Or do you want to remove the array because you have always one result?

Comment: How would you remove the index or change the index?

Comment: no there will be more than one result. This is just in a test database.

Comment: @DreadedSlug Objects are always of the form `{ "key": value, "key": value, ...}`. You can't have `{}` delimiters without `key:value` pairs inside.